# Why does Hive not like this query?

Tags: hive

`Ratingshive` table is dynamically partitioned on `Genre` and the table contains `movie_titles` and `rating of movies`

```
select 100 * stars / total 
  from (select count(rating) as stars 
    from ratingshive 
    where rating = 5) t1, 
  (select count(1) as total 
    from ratingshive) t2
```

When I run the above query in Hive, I get this error -

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:100 missing EOF at ',' near 't1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive does not like your query most probably because of old version. But you do not need to query the same `ratingshive` table two times and then cross join scalar results. Use aggregation with `case`:

```
select 100 * count(case when rating=5 then 1 end)/count(*) as rating_percent
  from ratingshive;
```